# Gaussian as a product of two independent random variables

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions

Ideally what I am looking for two random variables, $X$ and $Y$ (if one is positive then that's even better) such that $Z=X\cdot Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ where $X,Y$ are some distributions I can generate samples from. If anyone knows of a result like that it would be of great help.

I think  existence can be proven implicitly: Assume $X,Y$ have the same distribution. Let $m_k$ be the sequence of Gaussian moments and define $\tilde{m}_k=\sqrt{m_k}$, so it is enough to show that there exists a distribution with $\tilde{m}_k$ moments. That can be done by showing the moment sequence converges so the moment generating function is well defined, and get the density from the Laplace transform. Is that correct?

Comment: This question was asked at https://mathoverflow.net/q/199667 and eventually completely answered -- see the latest comment there, of Apr 2.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the repeated question but didn't pop up in the search.

Comment: $X=\pm 1$, $Y$ a half-normal distribution would do.